# Margins not working properly within iframe in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, margin

I'm working on a project and having some trouble with IE7.

I've got that has an iframe that takes up the whole page and loads another page. Cut down, it looks something like this:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Corporate Directory</title>
</head>
<body scroll="no" style="margin: 0;">

<iframe id="corpdir" height="100%" width="100%" frameborder="0" src="http://fullpath.to/corporate/directory" name="parent_frame">

</body>
</html>
```

Going to http://fullpath.to/corporate/directory works great in IE7, and there are no problems with rendering at all. But when it is loaded in the iframe like above, there are elements which get pushed to the left. All of these elements have a "margin-left" defined, but it seems like it's getting ignored. Not all elements with margin-left are being pushed over, just a few. I can't see anything in common about them that I could imagine would do this.

(Please don't ask why I was pretty much forced to load our webapp in a full screen iframe. Just accept that's it's pretty enterprisey and move on. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this:

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Corporate Directory</title>
</head>
<frameset>
  <frame src="http://fullpath.to/corporate/directory">
</frameset>
</html>
```

Didn't even realize there was no reason to be using an iframe there.